# Can anyone help me to identify these piano notes

Tags: piano

Im having trouble figuring this out. What is it called, and how do you play it? 
Thank you for all the help!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's a series of upward arpeggios.  The implication is that you should play the notes in the lower staff with your left hand, the ones in the upper staff with your right hand.  Hence the need for extra clefs.

It's a Dm7 chord then a G chord. We're told to 'change' the pedal when the chord changes - lift it so that the Dm7 is no longer sustained, put it straight down again to start sustaining the G.

Here's another (not necessarily better) way to notate it.[image]

Answer (score 2):

They're 32nd notes with a gazillion ledger lines and left-hand clef changes. You can tell they're 32nd notes because they all have 3 horizontal-enough beams.

The ledger lines are for the top staff for all notes with stems pointing down and for the bottom staff for all notes with stems pointing up (which is only the bottommost note with a ledger line).

Even worse, there's a damper-pedal-up marking followed by a damper-pedal-down marking at the second clef change.

Comment: Damper ped. change is because there's a different chord.